# Problem with exports.module and Firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, firebase-admin

I'm having a problem my code in the index looks like this:

```
const functions = require ('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require ('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require ('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow: debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest ((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient ({request, response});
    console.log ('Dialogflow Request headers:' + JSON.stringify (request.headers));
    console.log ('Dialogflow Request body:' + JSON.stringify (request.body));

    function SubmitFeedback (agent) {
        var functioncaoFeedback = require ('./EnviarFeedback');
        functionFeedback.SendFeedback (agent);
    }

    let intentMap = new Map ();
    intentMap.set ('inputName', CheckName);
    intentMap.set ('confirmFeedback', SendFeedback);
    intentMap.set ('InputMessage', CheckMessage);
    intentMap.set ('InputValues', CheckValue);
    intentMap.set ('negacaoFeedback', CheckNegacao);
    agent.handleRequest (intentMap);
});
```

And I'm calling the function "EnviarFeedback" of the file EnviarFeedback.js but it is giving errors in the log and the errors are:

> Unhandled rejection
>
> Function execution took 537 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

And here is the SubmitFeedback.js file:

```
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp ({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault (),
    databaseURL: 'https://pri-ambiente-de-teste.firebaseio.com/'
});

module.exports.SendFeedback = function (agent) {
    var context = agent.context.get ('result');
    var name = context.parameters.name;
    var value = context.parameters.valor;
    var message = context.parameters.mensagem;
    console.log (name, value, message);
    let banco = admin.database (). ref ('Data /');
    console.log (JSON.stringify (bank));
    return banco.push ({
        Name: name,
        Value: value,
        Message: message
    }, function (error) {
        if (error)
            console.log ('Error has occured during saving process')
        else
            console.log ("Data hss been saved succesfully")
    });
}
```

Comment: did you check this line `let banco = admin.database (). ref ('Data /');`?, you have a space, is this intended? If you can share more details, the current error doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like there is a space between the slash and the file name in your import. Maybe it's just that.

Anyway, you should also use a try/catch block to handle any exception in your code and log in the firebase console the error message.

Comment: It had no space it was time I copied it here and I went to edit it ended up going with space, even as it would be this try and catch because I tried it a few times and it gave an error or it didn't even work